# two lattices are equal if there is a matrix such that ...

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, geometry, riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces

[image]

I am trying to prove the previous lemma and I have thought to do the following: To go from right to left, I do not know how to proceed, but to go from left to right, it occurs to me to do the following.

Suppose that there is such a matrix, this means that $w_1'=aw_1+bw_2$ and $w_2'=cw_1+dw_2$, with which $\mathbb{Z}w_1'\oplus\mathbb{Z}w_2'=\mathbb{Z}(aw_1+bw_2)\oplus\mathbb{Z}(cw_1+dw_2)=\mathbb{Z}w_1\oplus\mathbb{Z}w_2$. Is this reasoning right? How do I prove the other implication? Thank you.

Comment: How do you get $\mathbb{Z}(aw_1+bw_2)\oplus\mathbb{Z}(cw_1+dw_2)=\mathbb{Z}w_1\oplus\mathbb{Z}w_2$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Now that I think about it carefully this is not entirely clear to me. I think a containment is clear $(\subset)$. but how can I prove the other contention? Is there an easier way to prove this? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

For $\omega_1'$, $\omega_2'$ to be a basis of $\Lambda$ it's necessary that
they are $\Bbb R$-linearly independent elements of $\Lambda$, that is
$$\pmatrix{\omega_1'\\\omega_2'}=A\pmatrix{\omega_1\\\omega_2}$$
where $A$ is a nonsingular integer matrix.

In this case $\omega_1'$, $\omega_2'$ do form a basis of some lattice $\Lambda'$.
For this to be the same as $\Lambda$ we need $\omega_1$, $\omega_2\in\Lambda'$,
so that
$$\pmatrix{\omega_1\\\omega_2}=B\pmatrix{\omega_1'\\\omega_2'}$$
for some integer matrix $B$. Then $BA=I$ which implies, $\det(B)\det(A)=1$
and so $\det A=\pm1$. But if $\det A=-1$ one shows that the sign of the imaginary
part of $\omega_1'/\omega_2'$ is opposite that of $\omega_1/\omega_2$. Therefore
$A\in\text{SL}_2(\Bbb Z)$.

Comment: Why does $BA = I$? We only know that $BA$ fixes $(\omega_1 \; \omega_2)^T$, which is different than 'being' the identity.