# Equality of two lattices in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, analysis

Given to lattices $\Gamma=\mathbb{Z}\omega_1+\mathbb{Z}\omega_2$ and $\Gamma'=\mathbb{Z}\omega_1'+\mathbb{Z}\omega_2'$ in $\mathbb{C}$, where $\omega_i,\omega_i'\in\mathbb{C}^*$, and $\text{Im}\frac{\omega_1}{\omega_2}\neq{0}$ and $\text{Im}\frac{\omega_1'}{\omega_2'}\neq{0}$, I want to show that $\Gamma=\Gamma'$ if and only if
\begin{equation}
\left(\begin{array}{c}
\omega_1 \\
\omega_2 
\end{array}\right)=A\left(\begin{array}{c}
\omega_1' \\
\omega_2' 
\end{array}\right)\end{equation}
for some $A\in\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$. However, I do not really know how to prove it for $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$. The proof is clear to me for $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$ with the condition that $\text{Im}\frac{\omega_1}{\omega_2}>0$ and $\text{Im}\frac{\omega_1'}{\omega_2'}>0.$ Then the $\Rightarrow$ direction is rather easy (the condition for the imaginary parts ensures that $\text{det}(A)=1$). However, for the $\Leftarrow$ direction I do not see why for example $\Gamma'\subset\Gamma$ if $A\in\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ instead of $A\in\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$. A little hint would be very much appreciated.

Comment: $A \in \text{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$ looks like the correct condition to me, compare e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3170169

Comment: Thank you! Yes I also found this post. Maybe it is just a typo here.